# Talend increment counter using parameter

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have to create a new talend job that add a new column in target table. I have to implement auto-incremental logic in the job ...

So that I have to get the maximum id plus one every time  I insert a value in the table for each time running the job ...

For example , If i run the job first time i have 100 records loaded to target table with max id (key is 100) - (so 100 records inserted)

Next time if i run the job for next set of data's for inserting 10 new or updating 10 old data, my key should be start as 101 to 110 for insert and same key shud be updated again in case of update job... Not again from 1 to 100 ... How to achieve in talend ... can u you suggest me ?

in tmap component can be achieved or which component to be used ? and also whether to use context / variable / expression ?? give me steps to achieve

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: I have included tmap component b/w input db component and o/p db component ... in tmap o/p component , i have added a new coloumn "key" and the expression used for that key cloumn is " Numeric.sequence("key",1,1) " but it wont achieve my req ... i have to use a global variable / context ... i need how to achieve ...